# Handlebars shorter if else?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm writing a handlebars template.

Is there a shorter way to write this :

```
<input type="text" id="date-from" value="{{#if dates.start}}{{dates.start}}{{else}}From{{/if}}" name="date-from"/>
```

I want to populate the `value` attribute if the `dates.start`value is present, other wise use a default value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nope, but what you can do is use a helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('shortIf', function(value) {
    if(value) {
        return value;
    }
    return "From";
});
```

Then you call it this way:

```
<input type="text" id="date-from" value="{{#shortIf dates.start}}" name="date-from"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to to Pablo's answer, but a more generic helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('iif', function(value, defaultValue) {
    return value || defaultValue;
});
```

Then, using the following template:

```
<input type="text" id="date-from" value="{{#iif dates.start 'From'}}{{/iif}}" name="date-from"/>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/J746R/